# MySQL - Update table with min date from another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table (`table1`) containing a user ID and transaction dates (`stt_stid`, `stt_date`) as well as some other non-relevant info.

I have another table (`table2`) with a couple hundred records that I need to get the `min(stt_date)` for based on `table1.stt_stid = table2.stid`.

`table1` is 5M + rows and I'm having trouble writing an efficient join without getting an error.

I've tried something along the lines of:

```
UPDATE table2 JOIN (
    SELECT stt_stid,
           MIN(stt_date) AS mindate
      FROM table1
     WHERE stt_amt > 0
       AND stt_prid = 1
     GROUP BY stt_stid) temp
    ON table2.stid = table1.stt_stid
 SET table2.firstdate = temp.mindate
```

Comment: The example query doesn't have a rowsource named `table1`, and there's and (implicit) `CROSS JOIN` between `temp` and `table2`... as shown, we'd expect the query to throw an error. (Assuming that the inline view is supposed to be referencing `table1`, make sure you've got an index `ON table1 (stt_stid, stt_date)`.

Comment: I updated the query - table1 is in the SELECT.  table1 has an index on the stt_stid, but not the date.

Comment: Add an index containing BOTH columns, `stt_stid` as the leading column (because of the GROUP BY), followed by `stt_date` (because of the MIN aggregate).

Comment: Please examine **what** you `JOIN` and what **table names / aliases** are used in the `ON` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that inline view query is supposed to be referencing `table1`, make sure you have an index defined

```
ON table1 (stt_stid, stt_date)
```

That will allow MySQL to make use of an index to satisfy the query. If MySQL can't use an index to satisfy the GROUP BY and get the minimum value, then that's going to require a "Using filesort" operation, on all the rows in `table1`, and that's expensive for large sets. (MySQL can make use of a suitable index to avoid that operation.)

The result from that inline view query is going to materialized as a "derived table", and then the outer query will run. Before MySQL 5.6, there won't be any index on the "derived table".

(I'm assuming that nearly every `stid` value in `table1` also appears in `table2`, that is, that `table2` doesn't contain a very small subset of `stid` values... if that's not the case, the moving a JOIN into the derived table may significantly reduce the size of the derived table.)